# Image not found 404 (next.js)

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack, compiler-errors, next.js

I use for my project custom webpack and it works great:

```
const path = require('path');
const Webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new Webpack.DefinePlugin([{
          __BROWSER__: "typeof window !== 'undefined'",
          __NETLIFY_BRANCH__: JSON.stringify(process.env.BRANCH),
          __CONFIG__: JSON.stringify({
            GRAPHQL_URL: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL,
            SEGMENT_WRITEKEY: process.env.SEGMENT_WRITEKEY,
          }),
        }])
      )
      config.module.rules.push(
        {
          test: /\.png$/,
          use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
           options: {
             limit: 10000,
             name: 'graphics/[name].[ext]',
            },
           },
         },
         {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
              }
            },{
              loader: 'string-replace-loader',
              options: {
                // this is a bugfix because react complains about the xmlns attribute.  Its not
                // a valid attribute according to react.  React devs also say it's not needed
                // for svg.
                search: ' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"',
                replace: '',
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                  },
            );
      return config;
  },
};
```

But also I try to import image to the project like:

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
render () {
    return (
    <img src={'../static/logo.svg'} alt="logo" />
  )
 }
}
```

Unfortunately, **I receive the error**, but the project is running.

```
http://localhost:3000/static/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

Layout in the directory "components" and images in directory "static". Both in the root.

Also I add JSON, maybe something wrong in dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^0.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "glamor": "^2.20.37",
    "glamor-media-query-presets": "^1.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.4",
    "localforage": "^1.5.0",
    "next": "^2.4.8",
    "react-apollo": "^1.4.8",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.1.4",
    "react-helmet": "^5.1.3",
    "typography": "^0.15.12",
    "typography-breakpoint-constants": "^0.15.10"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "next/babel"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "inline-react-svg",
        "transform-define",
        "./env-config.js"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^0.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "string-replace-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try this using absolute url, `<img  src ="http://localhost:3000/static/logo.svg>`

Comment: @abdul it is not ok for me, how I will deploy my project with this url?
And it does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Another option could be using require , `src={require('../logo.svg')}`

Comment: have you tried nextjs default Image component? sth like this:
import Image from 'next/image';
<Image width="24" height="24" src={'/logo.svg'} />
also add your images to public folder